# NodeJS: How to write async each loop at waterfall using jsdom

Tags: node.js

I am doing web scraping using jsdom at NODEJS. I tried so many ways like async.queue, series, etc etc. I am totally tied to find out the solution, I knew that I am in the end but no clue how to get all the models data.

Let us assume, I want to scrape all the categories and their products.

Categories --> products ---> models

```
Mobile (Category)               url is cat/mb 
    Iphone (product)            url is cat/mb/iphone
         Iphone 4 (model)       url is cat/mb/iphone/iphone-4
         Iphone 5 (model)       url is cat/mb/iphone/iphone-5

Laptop (Category)               url is cat/lp
     Sony (product)             url is cat/lp/sony
         F Series (model)       url is cat/lp/sony/fseries
         E Series (model)       url is cat/lp/sony/eseries
```

Concept is, getting all the categories and their products and their model info data.

**Expected output:**

```
I Phone 4
I Phone 5
F series
E series
```

But In my code I am missing so much models data **because of each loop in waterfall, not getting all the models info**, let us assume

**I am getting output as follows:**

```
F series
```

### **Main code is in the below**

```
async.each(pagination_values, function(paginateNum, callback) {
        var endpointUrl = catEndpointUrl + '&order=panel_id&by=desc&page='+paginateNum;//   'http://www.panelook.com/appmodlist.php?order=panel_id&by=desc&applications[]=CNS&page='+paginateNum;
        var baseurl = 'http://www.panelook.com/';
        logger.info('Step 4: Product Pagination '+ paginateNum + ' - ' + endpointUrl);
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback) {
                helperObj.fetchPageContent(endpointUrl, function(html) {
                    logger.info('Step 5: Product URL '+ endpointUrl);
                    callback(null, html);
                });
            },

            function(html, callback) {
                env({html:html,
                    done:function (err, window) {
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err.message);
                        var productList =[]
                        var $ = require('jquery')(window);
//............the below each function is not async i guess, Therefore, i am not getting all the models data..what to do ?...........
//
                        $('form#modelcompare   table#listable tr').each(function() {
                            if($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text() != ''){
                                logger.info('All the data ' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(2) a').attr('href'));
                            }
                        });
                    callback();
                }
            });
            }
        ], function(err, results) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err.message);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err.message);
    });
```

Comment: What are catEndpointUrl and pagination_values ? could you post these data also...

Comment: @Alexander  catEndpointUrl means category end point, lets say cat/mb, cat/lp. pagination_values means lets say i have sony product models,might be 1000 models. Therefore every page I am gonna iterate and get the models info, for instance  is cat/mb/iphone/paginate-1, cat/mb/iphone/paginate-2 so-forth. Well, coming to the main point i want to iterate the below each loop with aysnc mode. How could I do that.                                                                                               $('form#modelcompare   table#listable tr').each(function() {  .............              
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise with `q` ([link](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)).

Writing stuff in sequence is as easy as

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done();
```

Comment: i want to iterate the below each loop with aysnc mode, with out affecting async waterfall, How could I do that. $('form#modelcompare table#listable tr').each(function() { ............. });